# Android Programming - How to  play a SoundPool sound from a broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm very new to Android development and would like to know how to play a SoundPool sound within a  broadcastreceiver?

I read somewhere that using SoundPool is the way go play the sound but I don't know how to set it up properly.

I have some sound files such as wave and mp3 files in my Eclipse res\raw folder. I would like to play a file called half.wav

Can you show example code I need to place into my broadcastreceiver?

Here is a first attempt at the code but I do get an error stating that soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.half, 1);

"The Method Load(Context, Int, Int) In The Type SoundPool Is Not Applicable..."

Here is the code for the class:

```
package ChimeMe.BigBen;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
boolean loaded = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {

        // Load the sound
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });

        soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.half, 1);

        Toast.makeText(context, "This is the alarm.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Truly,
Emad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is just one sound you want to play I think using the MediaPlayer would be quicker and easier...

This is the code from an app of mine that plays a beep every 30 minutes when this Broadcastreceiver runs

```
public class Gameloop extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp = null;// Here 
    private static final String TAG = "VPET";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loop running");
        if (Pet.isAlive == true) {

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.beep);//Onreceive gives you context
            mp.start();// and this to play it

        } else {

        }
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Pheonix2105 for the coding sample. :-)